# How to make multiple Frames in Tkinter using OOP?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, frame

So, I was learning about class and methods and was trying to make multiple frames by using **init** method inside a class. The following is what I did:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import random
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    
    win = Tk()
    win.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    # Define Frame Class
    
    class MyFrame:
        def __init__(self, master):
            frame = Frame(master, width = win.winfo_screenwidth(),
                    height = win.winfo_screenheight(),
                    bg='black')
            frame.pack()
    
    def FrameOne():
        frameone = MyFrame(win)
    
    
    def FrameTwo():
        frametwo = MyFrame(win)

    #Call Frame (This is where I want the following frames to have different unique attributes)
    
    FrameOne()
    FrameTwo()
    
    win.mainloop()
```

My question is how can I set different Frame background, border and other Frame attributes to make each Frame have unique attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to specify frame arguments while using a class is by passing key word args through to the frame. This can be done pretty easily by adding `**kwargs` to the end of the arguments in init. then you can pass through all the arguments as you normally would while declaring a frame.

The code would look like:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win = Tk()
win.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
# Define Frame Class

class MyFrame:
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        frame = Frame(master, **kwargs)
        frame.pack()

def FrameOne():
    frameone = MyFrame(win, width = win.winfo_screenwidth(),
                       height = win.winfo_screenheight()//2,
                       bg='black')


def FrameTwo():
    frametwo = MyFrame(win, width=win.winfo_screenwidth(),
                       height = win.winfo_screenheight()//2,
                       bg='blue')

#Call Frame (This is where I want the following frames to have different unique attributes)

FrameOne()
FrameTwo()

win.mainloop()
```

Note: If you want to specify any default arguments to be applied to all the frames, add them before `,**kwargs` in the declaration.
Ex: `Frame(window, bg="white", **kwargs)`

Edit: *args, **kwargs:
*args is basically unpacking in a list format. *args accepts as many values as possible. if you print args, it'll output a list.

**kwargs is basically unpacking in a dictionary value. **kwargs accepts key-value pairs. if you print kwargs, it'll output a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Now I finally understand what **kwargs does. Would you tell me how it differs from **args ??

Comment: I edited my answer with a basic outline of *args and **kwargs